# Weird argv[1] x86_64 Linux Assembly

Tags: assembly, x86-64, nasm

I am getting the value of argv[1] is x86_64 Linux Assembly, but some extra bash stuff is being added onto the end. The only way I can remove it is by reserving less bytes, but argv[1] is going to be a dynamic value.

```
bits 64

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;          MACROS
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

%define SYS_WRITE 1
%define SYS_EXIT 60
%define EXIT_SUCESS 0

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;         SECTIONS
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

section .bss
    filename: resb 32

section .data
    usage_msg: db "Usage: ./pac <filename>", 10, 0
    usage_msg_len: equ $-usage_msg

section .text
    global _start

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;    PROGRAM ENTRY POINT
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
_start:
    pop rax                 ; pop argc into rax
    cmp rax, 2              ; make sure <filename> has been passed
    jl .not_enough_args

    jmp .enough_args

.not_enough_args:
    call print_usage
    jmp .exit

.enough_args:
    pop rax
    pop rax                 ; pop argv[1] into rax
    mov [filename], rax     ; move argv[1] into filename

    ; print filename for testing
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, SYS_WRITE
    mov rsi, [filename]
    mov rdx, 32
    syscall

    jmp .exit

.exit:
    mov rax, SYS_EXIT
    mov rdi, EXIT_SUCESS
    syscall

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;          CALLS
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

print_usage:
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, SYS_WRITE
    mov rsi, usage_msg
    mov rdx, usage_msg_len
    syscall
    ret
```

With this program, I am getting the following output:

```bash
$ ./pac file.txt
file.txtSHELL=/bin/bashSESSION
```

Please help me with this. Thank you.

Comment: You need to find out how long the string is (it's NUL terminated, so count the number of bytes until the NUL byte) and then only print that many bytes.

Comment: If you pipe your program's output into `hexdump -C`, you can see the `00` bytes (which print as zero-width on the terminal) you're also outputting.  The arg strings pointed-to by `argv[]` are followed by environment strings pointed to by `envp[]`, both on the stack.

Comment: If your program needs just one file, why don’t you simply use STDIN?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Been a while, and I decided to rewrite it. Not sure what I did differently, but I fixed it. I also added puts and strlen.

```
bits 64

%define SYS_WRITE 1
%define STDOUT 1
%define SYS_EXIT 60
%define EXIT_SUCCESS 0

section .bss
    prog: resb 32
    src: resb 32

section .data
    usage_arg1: db " <filename>", 10, 0

section .text
    global _start

_start:
    pop rax ; argc
    mov rdi, rax

    pop rax ; argv[0]
    mov [prog], rax
    mov rax, rdi
    
    cmp rax, 2
    jl .not_enough_args
    
    pop rax ; argv[1]
    mov [src], rax

    mov rsi, [src]
    call puts

    jmp .exit
    
.not_enough_args:
    call print_usage

.exit:
    mov rax, SYS_EXIT
    mov rdi, EXIT_SUCCESS
    syscall

; IN: rdi points to string
; OUT: rax contains string length
strlen:
    xor rax, rax
    dec rax
.top:
    inc rax
    cmp byte [rdi + rax], 0
    jne .top
    ret

; IN: rsi which points to a string
puts:
    push rax
    push rdi
    push rdx
    
    mov rdi, rsi
    call strlen
    mov rdx, rax
    
    mov rax, SYS_WRITE
    mov rdi, STDOUT
    syscall

    pop rdx
    pop rdi
    pop rax
    ret

print_usage:
    mov rsi, [prog]
    call puts
    mov rsi, usage_arg1
    call puts
    ret
```

Output:

```
$ ./prog
Usage: ./prog <filename>
```

```
$ ./prog file.txt
file.txt
```

Comment: *Not sure what I did differently* - obviously `write(1, ptr, strlen(ptr))` instead of `write(1, ptr, 32)` was the important change: passing a length to `write` that ends at the first `0` byte.  Exactly like commenters told you was the problem.